# How to programmatically call UITabbar from a tab/subview/subclass?

Tags: xcode4, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created a Tabbar Application using Xcode.

I have 5 different tabs and I want to select tab 1 from tab 3 so that tab 1 gets highlighted in the same way for the other tabs.

Is there a way to do this? If so is there any example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab indexes start at 0. so index 0 would be the first tab, index 1 would be the second tab etc.

So this is an example IBAction that will work (I just tested it) and send you to the second tab.

```
- (void)sendSecondTab:(id)sender
{
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: This link demonstrates how to create tabbar programmatically but i have created it using Tabbar Application in xcode. So what i need is to select a Tab from other tabs. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: So you want to create like a UIButton?  Not using the actual UITabBarController to go to the tab?

Comment: Yes i want to navigate to other tab on clicking on a UIButton. Can you please suggest me how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: jyap, I have already tried this but this only hightlights the tabbaar icon but dosen't loads the view. :( Thanks for taking time for me. Is there any other alternative for loading the first tab from the second tab.

Comment: Cool, what was wrong when you tried it the first time?  Can you mark my answer as 'Answered'?  Thanks!

Comment: Jyap actually i was trying to remove the view from the super view and trying to release the view after that i have added the code you suggested including remove from super view, so it was not working after removing all other code except code you suggested then it worked. I was using this code for Back button in the Navigation bar.

Comment: But when I used this same code for loading a different code it is not working. Is that I have to do anything else apart from this. Please suggest me. Or do I create another Question closing this on. If so what should the question.

Comment: You should create a more specific question closing this one. I would suggest adding a lot more detail because I can't understand your question without seeing more code.

Comment: Ok thanks I would create another question with some more details. :)

Comment: Jyap Have marked this question as answered and created a new question following is the question (xCode How to programmatically call UITabbar from a tab/subview/subclass using UIButton?) PLEASE HELP ME.